# Routing conflict Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, routes

I have two routes set up, where one takes an argument and another is just a URL that should route to a form where a new User can be created.  However, when I navigate to /users/create it seems like my getUser function is receiving the get request and sending me to my user.blade.php instead of my createUser.blade.php.

```
Route::get('/users/{id}', "UserController@getUser");
Route::get('/users/create', "UserController@createUser");
```

My methods in the UserController are:

```
  public function createUser(){
    //TODO: Handle user creation.
    return view('createUser');
  }

  public function getUser($id){
    $user = User::find($id);

    return view('userdetails', compact('user'));

  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better and much safer approach for handling this is

```
Route::get('/users/{id}', 'UserController@getUser')->where(['id' => '[0-9]+']);
Route::get('/users/create', 'UserController@createUser');
```

The `where()` tries to match the `id` field with a specific **regex/regular expression**. In this case `[0-9]` means **any integer between 0-9** and `+` indicates **multiple times** :)

Comment: Beautiful, this worked perfectly.  Just changed regex to match any positive integer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Change the order of them

```
Route::get('/users/create', "UserController@createUser");
Route::get('/users/{id}', "UserController@getUser");
```

Laravel will try to match routes top down and so you want the ones which are variable under similar matching ones.